# Can the verbs like deny,prohibit and refuse be take "not" with them or in the following phrase or clause

Tags: verbs

I read a sentence in the usage.
He denied not to go there,and the like sentence. I think deny is one of those non assertives

Comment: There was something wrong with your image link and my protection system alerted to it so I have edited it out.

Comment: _Deny, prohibit,_ and _refuse_ are all negative verbs. _Deny_ means 'say not', _prohibit_ means 'keep from doing', and _refuse_ means 'not do. They all license Negative Polarity Items like _ever_ and _in weeks_: _He denies that he's been there in weeks; She prohibited them from ever going again; I refuse to ever speak there_.

Comment: 'He denied not going there' sounds most unnatural. You'd use 'They accused him of lying when he said he'd already been to pay his respects at the grave, but he insisted he had.'

Comment: _*He denied not going there_ means -- and is as ungrammatical as -- _*He said he didn't not go there_.

Answer (score 3):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> *Deny, prohibit,* and *refuse* are all negative verbs. *Deny* means 'say not', *prohibit* means 'keep from doing', and *refuse* means 'not do. They all license Negative Polarity Items like *ever* and *in weeks*: *He denies that he's been there in weeks; She prohibited them from ever going again; I refuse to ever speak there*.

Comment: And therefore, since they're already negative, they don't have negatives in their complement clauses.

Comment: This is true, but I'm not sure whether it answers the OP's question. These verbs don't license negative concord, but they do all allow negative clauses. (It's not clear to me what the OP has in mind.)